# How to identify configured tasks in visual studio

Tags: nuget, visual-studio

I would like to understand an existing VS project build/publish scripts. this project was built using sitecore helix architecture. Currently i dont see any tasks configured for the project. In the task runner explorer i see 0 tasks. also i dont see any build/publish mechanism like gulp.js or grunt.js being used for the project. Only thing i see is bower json which i heard is used for deploying only client side specific files - css, js. my main aim is to compile and publish the whole project as a single click action, like to know is there any other build/publish mechanism involved for the entire project including c# code as dll. let me know how to identify it ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you find Cake somewhere?

Comment: There is no such files found in the solution. is this build mechanism part of sitecore habitat project structure ? if there is any other build mechanism tools for habitat project structure ?

Comment: Did you run command -> npm install ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command  "npm install" in your solution main folder and add the following files from the solution physical path into the configuration folder in the habitat .Net solution if they do not exist:

- gulpfile.js
- gulp-config.js